# Prove that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} {\left(-n,\frac1 n\right]} = (-\infty, 1]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that $$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} {\left(-n,\frac1 n\right]} = (-\infty, 1]$$

I understand that for this to be true, I have to show that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} {\left(-n,\frac1 n\right]} ⊂ (-\infty, 1]$ and
$(-\infty, 1]  ⊂ \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} {\left(-n,\frac1 n\right]}$, however, I'm stuck on figuring it out. I think the latter can be proven by contradiction somehow.

Comment: Consider an element $x \in (-\infty,1]$. Can you show that it is in the union?

Comment: Follow-up to Powerspawn's comment: consider an element $y\in(1,\infty)$. Can you show that it is not in the union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show mutual inclusion.

First suppose that $x \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big(-n, \frac{1}{n} \big]$. Choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in \big(-n, \frac{1}{n} \big]$. Since $x \leq \frac{1}{n} \leq 1$, $x \in (-\infty, 1]$. This shows that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big(-n, \frac{1}{n} \big] \subseteq ( - \infty, 1]$.

Conversely, suppose that $x \in (- \infty, 1]$. If $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we may choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Then $x \in (-n, \frac{1}{n} ]$, so $x \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big(-n, \frac{1}{n} \big]$. On the other hand, if $x < 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x > -n$. $x < 0 < \frac{1}{n}$, so $x \in (-n, \frac{1}{n}]$, so $x \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big(-n, \frac{1}{n} \big]$. This shows that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big(-n, \frac{1}{n} \big] \subseteq (- \infty, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first:
$$x\in\bigcup(-n,\frac{1}{n}] \rightarrow \exists n\in\mathbb{N}\ \text{s.t.} x\in(-n,\frac{1}{n}]$$
as $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and as $-n>-\infty$ then $x\in(-\infty,1]$

For the second, we know that for every number $a$ there exists number $b>a$ such that $b\in\mathbb{N}$, in the same way it works backwards, so that for every $a$ there exists $b<a$ such that $b\in\mathbb{Z}$

so:

if $0\leq x\leq1$ we take $n=1$,

else we take $n=y$ where $y$ is a smaller number than $x$ that is in $\mathbb{N}$ and satisfies that $y<x$, so we get that again $x\in(-y,\frac{1}{y}]$